# Python: Execute bat file via Network

Tags: python, batch-file, networking, network-programming

I am trying to execute a bat file which is stored on a different machine on my network and I want this file to be executed on the machine on which it is stored.

Ie, Say I am using PC "A" and I have a bat file on PC "B" & "C".
Now I want to have a python script which will allow me to select the machine via UI (later), ie "A" or "B" and then execute the script stored the network machine.

Is there a way to do that in Python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). It's standalone but probably can be launched from Python